# How to do a calculation faster in python with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have some huge data in a python dictionary,
say, it contains sales data for company A, and company B.
It takes too long time to do the sales analysis for these 2 companies.

Is there a way to divide the dictionary into 2 (company A and B), and do calculations on 2 CPU cores, so that it will be faster? Company A and B's sales analysis are independent from each other.

Lets say my dictionary is like this:

```
sales_data = {"COMPANY A":[1,2,3.....100],"COMPANY B":[1,2,3.....200]}
```

then I want to sum the numbers in 2 inner lists above, which will give me the total amount of sales for each company.
1 CPU core will sum sales numbers for `company A`,
other CPU core will sum sales numbers for `company B`.

If only 1 CPU does this job, it will first  sum sales numbers for `company A`, and then will sum sales numbers for `company B`. But if 2 cores divide this job, the whole calculation will be done in a shorter time.

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def job(xs):
    return sum(xs)


sales_data = {"COMPANY A":[1,2,3.....100],"COMPANY B":[1,2,3.....200]}

p = Pool()
p.map(job, sales_date.values())
```

**NB:** This will NOT work as your "sample" data is not valid Python.

*Please also note:*

- Whilst this in general is the structure of many "multiprocessing embarrassingly parallel" problems this will not solve any problem that you just split up data for (necessarily*).
- If your data is large, a large amount of serialization *will* occur between parent and child processes.
- If your data is larger than what will fit into Memory then you have a different problem; one in which will involve different algorithms to process the data.

Comment: Sir, when I ran the code you provided, my CPU was going to get burned, and I had to restart the PC.